# How to send parameter by controller (Spring) to an Angularjs module for display in jsp?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to send a parameter as follows:

My controller (Spring), mynamePage.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myname", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String mynamePage(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("myname", "eloy");
    return "myname";
}
```

My module:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('inspinia')
})();
```

Add controller Angular:

```
function MainCtrl() {
    var name = "${myname}";
    this.userName = name;    
};

angular
    .module('inspinia')
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl)
```

In JSP:

```
<span>
  <strong>{{main.userName}}</strong> //Show ${myname}
  <strong>${myname}</strong> // Show eloy
</span>
```

I'm trying to have myname recognized by userName in angular but it launches a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you are trying to use this in your **angularjs** file. Please,  remember
`${myname}` is a jsp tag.
So, you have to use this in your `.jsp` page/file, not in `.js` file.

**Suggestion**

You can do this if you implement your angular controller in your `jsp/java` page/file

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it guides me a lot.